# Two figures are redrawn and merged into one. Are reproduction permissions required in this case?

Tags: publications, copyright, online-publication, copy-editing

I have two questions regarding writing of survey papers

Firstly, if one of the technical papers reviewed has a number of figures. Take for example: Figure 4 is "Data model" and Figure 8 is "Mechanism structure". In the survey paper is it enough modification (for a waver of official permission) to merge these two into one figure and cite. Say, Figure X: Data model and Mechanism Structure adapted from [ref]?

Secondly, in the case when author A proposes "Data model" and "mechanism structure" in paper [30] and [35] i.e four entirely different diagrams. Is it sufficient as modification (for a waver for official permission) if in a survey, all four combined in one figure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we have no idea about the content of the paper, and this is a problem that must be solved by the authors.

Comment: Someone out there could have some knowledge that might benefit millions of people in the future. For instance, a link etc. It is not sufficient for any author to solely depend on the answers here, but may be they get some guidance. Furthermote, publications have general ethics that one could always inquire about. If you need more clarifications you could ask. Besides, the question could be edited by anyone capable of doing so. I think practical questions should not be down-voted

Comment: I believe this is not a matter of knowledge, but matter of principals and perspective. And those things are unfortunately not global.

Comment: At least we know what are those principles and what should be put to perspective. Then, which channels are best referred to. May be someone is there that would prevent such questions from being asked again by giving clear insights on such matters

Comment: This is very much a legal question that depends on jurisdiction and on the creative or intellectual added-value provided by the author who builds on the original materials (in this case you, the OP). The latter is impossible to assess without seeing the originals and modifications, and the answer would thus depend on individual factors. Voting to close.

Comment: This is quite specific to what you've done. If you've just dropped the four images as-is into a,b,c and d subfigures then yes. The more modifications you make, the less likely you will need permission. If in doubt, ask your university librarian, publisher or an IP lawyer for specialist advice. Or, as I suggested on your previous question (https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/103942/do-i-need-an-explicit-permission-to-publish-someone-else-s-table-in-another-pape), it's usually so easy to obtain permission that you might as well just do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining other people's published figures to create a new figure does **not** allow you to waive requests for permission to reproduce a figure. Each individual component is someone else's intellectual property, and they have the right to be credited for the work. Note that many journals have simple mechanisms for requests to reproduce, and usually it's just a matter of asking for the necessary permission.

Simply redrawing someone else's figures for a part (a) and (b)-type figure does not spare you from requesting permissions. If you have completely redrawn and combined figures (for example, to illustrate how the two figures are more closely connected than in the originals), then you are creating a new intellectual contribution. You need to cite the original work that you've adapted, but you would not be reproducing the figures, and therefore would most likely not need to secure reproduction permissions.